# Help with modal text input for new table item

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, modal-dialog

first let me start by saying I'm pretty new to iPhone, so I apologise for my ignorance.

I've got a UITableView that I want to add new items to.  When the add button is pressed, I want a modal screen to slide up where the user types in the text for the new item.

I've been reading from Apple's [Table View Programming Guide for iPhone](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH10-SW5), and they have an example that supposedly does what I want:

```
- (void)addItem:sender {
// To add an item, display a modal view with a text field.
if (itemInputController == nil) {
    itemInputController = [[ItemInputController alloc] init];
}
// Use a navigation controller to provide a customizable navigation bar with Cancel and Done buttons.
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:itemInputController];
[[self navigationController] presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];
[navigationController release];
```

}

However they don't explain anywhere what itemInputController is.  As far as I can determine it is supposed to give me a modal view with a single text field, and a navigation bar with Cancel and Save in it.  Am I supposed to create this view myself in Interface Builder?  Or is it a standard thing I need to import somehow?  Can anyone help me decipher this, or alternatively show me another way to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ItemInputController will be a derivitave of UIViewController that you need to add to your project.

You'll need to create a new UIViewController subclass, then build the interface in IB - [see here](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/6206-how-create-uiview-uiviewcontroller-programatically-without-using-nib.html) for a discussion on building UIViewControllers.